# How can I compile Python3 to work on Fedora Core 5

Tags: python, fedora-core

Stuck with hardware on remote machines (around 2000 of them), running Fedora Core 5 (yes very old), the only package RPM wise i can get for this for python is 2.4, and i really need to be able to make use of Python 3 (ideally 3.5 or 3.6).

Is there any way i can do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried following https://devguide.python.org/setup/ the setup guide?

Comment: Hi,  Yes but too many additional requirements that are outdated, and need updating is the issue, and it means you have build that from source, then that has its own set of requirtements and that needs building from sorce also and on and on...